# Is nbm-maven-plugin safe to be used for maven parallel build?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, parallel-builds, maven-nbm

I have a multi module project that uses nbm-maven-plugin. I'm currently testing out the parallel build feature from maven 3. Very happy with the result as it improves the speed by almost 60% :) The problem is, it doesn't seem to be marked as thread safe yet.

I have tried to use the latest version 3.10.1, and I'm still receiving the warning. There is no issue logged regarding this in the [tracker](http://jira.codehaus.org/issues/?jql=project%20=%20MNBMODULE) too (wanted to create the issue but I can't seem to register?).

So my question is, are they safe to be used? I can build successfully so far, but I don't think building successfully will conform the thread safeness of nbm-maven-plugin.

Comment: Have you tried this: `Sign-up for a JIRA account
You will need to create an account in Xircles - https://xircles.codehaus.org/signup/ - this became necessary to combat spammers who had automated JIRA signups. ` to sign up for jira?

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you! Created the [issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNBMODULE-217)